# Absolute Extrema: $f(x)=\frac{2x+5}{3}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I have to locate the absolute extrema of the given function:

> $$f(x)=\frac{2x+5}{3}$$

I found the derivative and set it equal to zero, and it can't equal zero ($f'(x)=\frac{2}3\therefore\frac23\ne0$) The interval where I have to find the absolute extrema is in the interval of $[0,5]$.  I am new to finding the absolute and I deduced that the extrema is one of the end-points particularly $x=5$. Is my assumption correct or is the there no absolute extrema?

Comment: Your analysis is correct but necessarily complicated.  What kind of curve is $f(x)$?  It is a line!  And what do you know about lines?  Both end points are extrema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f'(x)=\frac23>0$ on the interval, the function is strictly increasing there. Thus, the smallest value is at the left end and the largest value at the right end of the interval.

P.S. Note that the term *extrema* is used for both - the maximum as well as for the minimum. So in this case you have got *two* absolute extremas: one is the global min, another is the global max.